# JQuery get current select current option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have different selects (for quantity) after a button

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2" >Button1</button>
                    <select  id="quantity1"  class="ml-1">

                        <option value="4">4</option>

                    </select>

                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2" >Button2</button>
                    <select  id="quantity1"  class="quantity ml-1"> 

                        <option value="3">3</option>

                    </select>
```

what I want is when I click button1 I receive 4 and when to Click on button2 I receive 3.

something like

```
 var nextoption =   $('button[id*="addtocart"]').click(function()  { console.log($(this).closest('select').text()); });
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is used to get the nearest *parent* element matching the selector. The `select` elements are siblings, so you need `next()` instead. Also, to get the value of the selected option, use `val()`:

```js
var nextoption = $('button[id*="addtocart"]').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).next('select').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2">Button1</button>
<select id="quantity1" class="ml-1">
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2">Button2</button>
<select id="quantity1" class="quantity ml-1">
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** method to get the next sibling element of the buttons and, as always, use the **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** method to extract the current value of a form field.

```js
$("button[id*='addtocart']").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).next().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2" >Button1</button>
<select  id="quantity1"  class="ml-1">
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2" >Button2</button>
<select  id="quantity1"  class="quantity ml-1"> 
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:selected` to access the selected option.

---

```js
$('#addtocart1').click(() => {
  console.log($('#quantity1 option:selected').val());
});

$('#addtocart2').click(() => {
  console.log($('#quantity2 option:selected').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart1">Button1</button>
<select id="quantity1" class="ml-1">
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="addtocart2">Button2</button>
<select id="quantity2" class="quantity ml-1">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```